# Converter strings para booleanos

Tags: javascript, string, querystring, booleano

Estou adicionando dinamicamente um `javascript` e ao seu `src` preciso passar alguns parâmetros... a seguinte função cria esta "querystring":

```
var querystring = {a:'b',b:true,c:'d',e:false};
var query = Object.keys(querystring).map((key) => {return [key, querystring[key]].map(encodeURIComponent).join("=");}).join("&");

// output: "a=b&b=true&c=d&e=false"
```

Estes valores são usados como argumento de configuração do `javascript` adicionado... para resgatar estes valores para um `object` uso a seguinte função:

```
var scripts = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    query = false;

for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
     if ( (/module-name\/index.js/g.test(scripts[i].src)) ) {
         query = scripts[i].src.split('?')[1];
     }
}
if ( !!query ) {
    query = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(query.replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g,"\":\"")) + '"}');
    console.log(query);

    // output: {a: "b", b: "true", c: "d", e: "false"}
```

O problema consiste que justamente preciso observar os valores como booleanos más não sei como fazer isto.

Ao adicionar mais 2 `replace()` para substituir booleanos se o ultimo argumento for um booleano retorna uma `string` exemplo:

```
// exemplo 1:
var query = "a=b&b=true&c=d&e=false";
query = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(query.replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g,"\":\"")).replace(/"true"/g, true).replace(/"false"/g, false) + '"}');

console.log(query);

// output: {a:'b',b:true,c:'d',e:"false"};


// exemplo 2:
var query = "a=b&b=true&c=d&e=false&foo=bar";
query = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(query.replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g,"\":\"")).replace(/"true"/g, true).replace(/"false"/g, false) + '"}');

console.log(query);

// output: {a:'b',b:true,c:'d',e:false,foo:'bar'};
```

Como posso resolver isto? Caso o ultimo item desta "querystring" for um booleano de fato retornar um booleano?

Answer (score 2):

## Não use regex e nem qualquer outra manipulação direta da string

Como você mesmo já percebeu, esta não é a melhor solução (além de, na minha opinião, deixar o código desnecessariamente mais complicado).

Já existe uma solução nativa para manipular *query strings*, que é a [interface `URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). Com ela, fica muito mais simples fazer a verificação que você quiser. Um detalhe é que todos os valores são tratados como strings, então basta converter manualmente os que você precisa:

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams('a=b&b=true&c=d&e=false');
var result = {};
for (var [name, value] of params) {
    if (value === 'true') {
        value = true;
    } else if (value === 'false') {
        value = false;
    }
    result[name] = value;
}
console.log(result); // { a: 'b', b: true, c: 'd', e: false }
```

Transformar as strings "true" e "false" em booleanos é meio chato. Uma string não vazia é considerara verdadeira, então não bastaria só comparar com "true" e considerar qualquer outra coisa como falsa, tem que testar exatamente as duas strings. Também daria para fazer algo como:

```js
if (value === 'true' || value === 'false') {
    value = JSON.parse(value);
}
```

Mas acho desnecessário usar o *parser* de JSON para dois valores tão simples, e que eu já posso saber quais são e usar diretamente nas atribuições.

---

Se quiser **muito** continuar manipulando a string manualmente (o que eu não recomendo, já que `URLSearchParams` é menos propenso a erros, além de ser a ferramenta mais adequada para a tarefa), então basta usar uma função auxiliar no `JSON.parse`, que trata as strings "true" e "false":

```js
var query = "a=b&b=true&c=d&e=false";
query = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(query.replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g,"\":\"")) + '"}',
                   function(key, val) {
                       // se a string é "true" ou "false"
                       if (val === 'true') {
                           return true;
                       } else if (val === 'false') {
                           return false;
                       }
                       return val;
                   });
console.log(query); // { a: 'b', b: true, c: 'd', e: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez não seja a melhor solução, mas você pode saber se é um valor booleano da seguinte maneira:

```
var isTrue = (query.e == "true"); //compara com a string "true" e retorna true, caso sejam iguais
```

Comment: O `object` retornado da `querystring` (caso haja) sera mesclado ao objeto **defaults** no fonte... como estas opções são exclusivamente `booleans` e usadas extensivamente no fonte não posso verificar cada entrada até porque o "módulo" pode ser extendido :(